# Am I using %c wrong?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I'm making a choice-based story, and after I ask the user to press enter, the option comes up on which class they wan't their character to be. Every time, this window pops up and says "'legends.exe' has stopped working."

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char firstname[15];
    char class;
    char swordch0c1;
    char enter;

    printf("Hello there! Could I have your first name?\n");
    scanf("%s",firstname);
    printf("\n---------------------The Legend of %s---------------------",firstname);
    printf("\nPress Enter to continue.");
    enter=getch();
    if(enter=="\n");

    printf("\n\n\nYou are %s, a: \nA.Swordsman\nB.Assassin\nC.Archer\nD.Mage\n",firstname);
    scanf("%c",class);
    return(0);
}
```

I'm sorry if I'm being difficult or not specific enough.BTW, I'm using windows.

Comment: share a exact code which causing problem.

Comment: u should scanf into the address of the variable... ex. `scanf(&class)`

Comment: Every C developer at some point realises the inadequacy of the lower level input functions (for example, my _real_ name is `Tarquin Fin-tim-lin-bin-whin-bim-lim-bus-stop-F'tang-F'tang-Olé-Biscuitbarrel` and your code appears to crash for me every time), and writes a better, safer, faster, smarter, more handsome one :-) Here's mine: http://powerfield-software.com/?p=65. Use it as you will, and concentrate more on the logic of your game.

Comment: @paxdiablo your `getLine()` only solves one of many problems with inputs longer than their intended buffer: it will avoid a desync where the long last name spills into the next input prompt. That's rarely all that's required; instead many times the right thing to do is allocate a larger buffer that *can* fit the entire input.

Comment: Adam, no function can solve _every_ problem, you have to draw the line somewhere. For example, if no memory can be allocated, what do you do? The function in the link solves the most prevalent problem, the one that will _crash_ your code. It replaces it with something that can both prevent that and notify you when your input won't fit in the buffer. _How_ you handle that notification is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
scanf("%c",class);
```

with

```
scanf("%c",&class);
```

You need to give `scanf` a pointer to where you want it to put the data.

Note that `class` is not the best name for a variable. While it's not a keyword in C, it is in many languages.

Comment: same applies to `scanf(firstname)` :p

Comment: Wow. I feel really dumb now. I knew that. I guess I just forgot. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
scanf("%c", &class);
```

Comment: Guys, posting duplicate answers with no additional info is a good way to get down-votes...

Comment: woops! yeah apologies for that!, new to answering questions :). will provide explanations to further answers. Adam was just literally .2 seconds faster to post an answer than me. I was just .2 seconds late from answering first. This was not a duplicate answer but I agree with further explanations needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The last `scanf` must contain `&`:

```
    scanf("%c",&class);
```

`&` is the address of operator and you need it before the variable name in `scanf`. `scanf` expects pointer argument(s) or in other words pointer to the variable(s) and not the variable itself.

```
    if(enter=="\n");
```

Has no effect here. Change it to

```
    if(enter=='\n')
    {...}
```

Comment: I know what you're trying to say, Cool Guy, but it could be misunderstood. Certainly, the args to `scanf()` (and friends) that receive data **must** be pointers. But that doesn't mean that you must _always_ use the `&` _address of_ operator, since it's quite legal (and reasonably common) to pass entities that are declared to be pointers as args.

Comment: @PM2Ring , Yup! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax, you need to specify the &

scanf("%c",&class);

Answer (score 0):

This will work 100%.

scanf("%c",&class);